# Method calling kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm sure there is already an answer for this, but I'm very new and a lot of the answers I found look overly complicated and well past my experience as a programmer.

I created a class with a method, I wish to call on that method to display after it promts the user for input. I know where to call on the method. But don't know how to in kotlin. PLEASE HELP!

Here's my code

```
fun main() {
println("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit")
}

class ComputeMethods(){
    fun tempConversion(degreesF: Double){
        var degreesF = readln().toDouble()
        var degreesC = (degreesF - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
        var conversion = "$degreesF degrees Fahrenheit = $degreesC degrees Celsius"
        println(conversion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to read user input inside `main()` and pass it to the method

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit")
    ComputeMethods().tempConversion(readln().toDouble())
}

class ComputeMethods(){
    fun tempConversion(degreesF: Double){
        var degreesC = (degreesF - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
        var conversion = "$degreesF degrees Fahrenheit = $degreesC degrees Celsius"
        println(conversion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what's confusing you here is you're creating a class and putting the method inside that, as a member function. That means to actually call that method, you need to create an *instance* of the class:

```
val methods = ComputeMethods()
```

and then call the method on that object:

```
methods.tempConversion(degrees)
```

Or all in one line, chaining the creation and call together:

```
ComputeMethods().tempConversion(degrees)
```

That's something you'll often do, but in this case it makes more sense to just have the function as a top-level function, like `main` is:

```
fun main() {
    println("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit")
    // use a val if you don't need to change the value later
    val degreesF = readln().toDouble()
    val conversion = tempConversion(degreesF)
    println(conversion)
}


fun tempConversion(degreesF: Double) {
    var degreesF = readln().toDouble()
    var degreesC = (degreesF - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
    var conversion = "$degreesF degrees Fahrenheit = $degreesC degrees Celsius"
}
```

I've moved things around a bit, but you can see that now you can just call `tempConversion` like any other function, it's just *there* (it's visible in the scope, if you want to get technical). Utility functions often work like this, where you don't need an instance of a class to access them.

---

**(the rest of this might be a bit complicated if you're new to this, don't worry about it if it doesn't all make sense - just giving you an idea of things you can do)**

If you *did* want to organise things inside an object like that (as a kind of namespace) you could create an `object`:

```
object ComputeMethods {
    fun tempConversion(degreesF: Double) {
        ...
    }
}
```

An `object` is like a singleton instance of a class - you don't need to create it, and there's only one of them that everything uses. So you can call your function inside it like this:

```
ComputeMethods.tempConversion(degrees)
```

You have to access the function *through* the object, but that can be nice for organisation - you can keep all your *compute methods* together, and it's clear exactly where that function is when you call it. Nice if your function has a generic name too!

---

You can also do that on an actual *class* too, if you want, by putting functions inside its *companion object*:

```
class SomeThing {
    companion object {
        fun coolFunction()
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function through the class itself, `SomeThing.coolFunction()`. The difference with the `object` approach up there is that this is a *class* that you want to create instances of, objects you use. But the `companion object` allows you to add functions and properties that aren't tied to any specific instance, you can just access them through the class name, as "something related to the class as a whole". The plain `object` version up there is useful if you don't need the instances at all.